# "text-align:right" doesn't work properly on IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, css-float

I have the following structure:

```
<div><input type='text'/><a></a></div>
```

Div is text-aligned right and input is floated left. At first input is hidden. Whenever I make the input visible, link moves to left in IE7. But in FF3 link stays where it is. What is the reason of the link's move and how can I make it stay still in IE7?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6U48e/2/) is the fiddle.

Comment: Why are you testing in Firefox 3?

Comment: I have only FF3 as non-IE browser. I prefer the link stay in its place on all browsers.

Comment: FF3 should be at least upgradable to 3.6...But you know, FF10 is latest version which upgrades automatically.

Comment: I can't understand when FF reached tenth version. I downloaded the third version at most one year ago. anyway, could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
.questionfooter a {
    float: right;
}
```

For consistent result, use `float: left;` for the input and `float: right` for the link.

Comment: Ok, this works great but do you know why the previous version was inconsistent?

Comment: @sevenkul Which version are you talking about.. As far as I know, The above should work in all versions.. but please note that containers (div's) are supposed to be floated not the elements (input, a). I am not sure if it is the convention or any issue in floating elements.

Comment: Anyway, let it work this way. I will not use `text-align:right;` for aligning but use `float:right;` then.

Answer (score 0):

For IE7 use css as below. Looks like you using display:none; for input to hide it.

```
.IE7 input {visibility:hidden;}
```

Comment: There is no problem with visibility. Moreover, does jQuery recognizes an element having style "visibility:hidden;" as a hidden element so that .show() function works for it?